# Projectivity of equivariant K-theory of toric variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I'm looking at Vezzosi and Vistoli's paper: [Higher algebraic K-theory for actions of diagonalizable groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0107174).

In Theorem 6.9, they prove that the $T$-equivariant K-theory of a smooth projective toric variety is a projective module over the representation ring of $T$. (Their result seems more general but this is the case I'd like to understand.)

I cannot see how that follows from what's written in Section 6.3. Can anyone explain what they have in mind?